# How do I stop the function triggering onChange every time?

Tags: javascript, html-select, onchange

I'm creating an app that allows a teacher to create a report for a student. My [current jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanCUK89/x1swe6Lk/1/) shows the full code, and it has the basic functionality I want.
However, at the moment the printSelection function runs onChange when the user chooses from the options, adding the selection to collatedArray.

```
function printSelection(e) {
  collatedArray.push(e.value);
  console.log(collatedArray);
}
```

The problem is, if the user changes their mind it then adds both of the options to final report.

Is there a way to run this function but only if the user has not made a selection from it before?

Comment: `let selection = e.value;` then `if (selection === e.value) {` that doesn't make sense, it's always truthy! you are assigning that value to the variable `selection` then check aginst it?! just remove that if statement cause it does nothing

Comment: Thanks @SaymoinSam. I've removed it now - thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, and pls consider posting stack snippets for your live code instead of external links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you are pushing data on each `onchange` event, and doing so will only work if the user selects only once, but you can avoid that by using a simple object to hold your data and each time the user selects it overwrites the correct property that way you will store only the desired input, here is a simple example, note that you can use event delegation like me, instead of adding an event listener to each `<select>` element, and pls avoid using inline **JS** it has lot of disadvantages.

```js
var inputsElement = document.querySelector("#dropdown-inputs"),
  inputs = {};

inputsElement.onchange = function(e) {
  // note that I'm not checking for the type of element
  // because I have just two <select> elements so it's
  // obvious that one of them is triggering the "onchange" event
  // so I set the right property name according to the select element
  inputs[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  // just for debugging ;)
  console.clear();
  console.log(inputs);
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-inputs">
  Width:
  <select name="width">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
  </select>
  Height:
  <select name="height">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've used this to get it working. Thanks so much, great and simple solution!